# Why the division of two integers return 0.00?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

Every time I run this program I get different and weird results. Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 5, b = 2;
    printf("%.2f", a/b);
    return 0;
}
```

- [Live Demo](https://ideone.com/jnqter)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
printf("%.2f", a/b);
```

The output of the division is again of type `int` and not `float`.

1. You are using wrong format specifier which will lead to undefined behavior.
2. You need to have variables of type float to perform the operation you are doing.

The right format specifier to print out `int` is `%d`

Answer (score 7):

In your code, `a` and `b` are of type `int`, so the division is essecntially an integer division, the result being an `int`.

You cannot use a wrong format specifier anytime. `%f` requires the corresponding argument to be of type `double`. You need to use `%d` for `int` type.

FWIW, using wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

From `C11` standard,  chapter §7.21.6.1, *`fprintf()`*

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

If you want a floating point division, you need to do so explicitly by either

- promoting one of the variable before the division to enforce floating point division, result of which will be of floating point type.

  ```
  printf("%.2f", (float)a/b);
  ```
- use `float` type for `a` and `b`.

Comment: IMHO.. Just answer to the point is good.. Adding this much information for simple answer I feel is unnecessary and might lead to confusion for OP

Comment: IMHO, this answer is not _just_ meant for OP. It may be useful for someone visiting in future. You never know. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the type as float or double.

Something like this:

```
printf("%.2f", (float)a/b);
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/N6Ley0)**

`%f` format specifier is for `float`. Using the wrong format specifier will lead you to undefined behavior. The division of int by an int will give you an int.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of your printf()

```
printf("%.2lf",(double)a/b);
```

Comment: sorry, but why you need `double` here?

Comment: We could do with float as well .Its just my habit to work with doubles when decimals are concerened.

Comment: Right, When you don't mention that and simply change the `float` to `double`, it _may_ leave wrong impression to OP. Just saying.